# Create new column in DataFrame based on comparison against row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a1': [1,2,3,4],
               'des_2': ['a','b','a', 'd'],
               'des_4': ['a','c','c', 'd'],
               'des_1': ['a','b','c', 'd'],
               'des_3': ['a','b','c', 'a'],
               'a2': [1,2,3,4],
               'a3': [1,2,3,4]
               })
```

And I want to create a new column that shows the number of adjacent repeats of the first value, taking into account only the columns with 'des_', ordered alphabetically.

In the first row, all occurences are equal to a, so the count adds up to 4. In the second row, des_1, des_2, and des_3 are equal to b, so the cound adds up to 3. And so on.

```
   a1  des_2  des_4  des_1  des_3  a2  a3  count
0  1   a      a      a      a      1   1   4
1  2   b      c      b      b      2   2   3
2  3   a      c      c      c      3   3   1
3  4   d      d      d      a      4   4   2
```

I have a working code, but I feel it's not very pythonic:

```
cols_list = sorted(df.columns.tolist())
cols_list = list(filter(lambda x: 'des_' in x, cols_list))

new_df = df[cols_list]
lists = new_df.values.tolist()
occ_list = []
for lst in lists:
    first_occurrence = lst[0]
    counter = 0
    for occurrence in lst:
        if occurrence == first_occurrence:
            counter += 1
        else:
            break
    occ_list.append(counter)
    counter = 0

df['count'] = occ_list
```

Any idea how to reduce it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is the count of row 3 (index 2) shown as 1? There are two adjacent "c" values in `des_3` and `des_4`

Comment: Hi not_speshal! Because I only want to count the first set of adjacent ocurrences of the des columns, sorted alphabetically. des_1 has a 'c', but des_2 has an 'a'

Comment: Oh got you. Let me edit my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a1': [1,2,3,4],
               'des_2': ['a','b','a', 'd'],
               'des_4': ['a','c','c', 'd'],
               'des_1': ['a','b','c', 'd'],
               'des_3': ['a','b','c', 'a'],
               'a2': [1,2,3,4],
               'a3': [1,2,3,4]
               })

df_des = df.filter(like='des_').sort_index(axis=1)
df['count'] = (
               (df_des == df_des.shift(1, axis=1).bfill(axis=1))
                   .cumprod(axis=1)
                   .sum(axis=1)
              )
df
```

Output:

```
   a1 des_2 des_4 des_1 des_3  a2  a3  count
0   1     a     a     a     a   1   1      4
1   2     b     c     b     b   2   2      3
2   3     a     c     c     c   3   3      1
3   4     d     d     d     a   4   4      2
```

Explanation:

- First, subset the dataframe using `filter` with `like` parameter to
  get only columns with 'des_' and sort alphabetically with
  `sort_index`.
- Next, compare with shifted dataframe using `shift` with `axis=1` use `bfill` to backwards fill
  NaN.
- Use `cumprod` to only count the first consecutive repeats, once a
  different value is found cumprod will keep zeroes.
- Lastly, `sum` with `axis=1`

Answer (score 2):

What is "pythonic" is very subjective but here is one way you can reduce your code:

```
#function to return the longest streak of the first element
def streak(srs):
    groups = (srs!=srs.shift()).cumsum()
    return srs.groupby(groups).size().iat[0]

#keep only the columns you need in the correct order
sample = df[[f"des_{i+1}" for i in range(4)]]
df["count"]= sample.apply(streak, axis=1)

>>> df
   a1 des_2 des_4 des_1 des_3  a2  a3  count
0   1     a     a     a     a   1   1      4
1   2     b     c     b     b   2   2      3
2   3     a     c     c     c   3   3      1
3   4     d     d     d     a   4   4      2
```